# parsing error while parsing api response to python2.7 using loads

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am calling an api to get metrics from a python2.7 application like this

```
metrics = service.projects().metricDescriptors().list(
         name=project_name,
         pageSize=config.PAGE_SIZE,
         pageToken=next_page_token
    ).execute()
```

the metrics has  list of values like this: Thre response is coming in this form

```
    {
u'displayName': u'Daily active users', u'name': u'projects/my-projecc/metricDescriptors/actions.googleapis.com/smarthome_action/num_active_users', u'metricKind': u'GAUGE', u'valueType': u'INT64', u'labels': [{u'description': u"Assistant Smarthome trait. e.g.: 'onOff', 'colorSetting', 'lockUnlock', etc.", u'key': u'trait'}], u'launchStage': u'BETA', u'monitoredResourceTypes': [u'assistant_action_project'], u'metadata': {u'ingestDelay': u'180s', u'samplePeriod': u'60s', u'launchStage': u'BETA'}, u'type': u'actions.googleapis.com/smarthome_action/num_active_users', u'unit': u'1', u'description': u'Daily active users count.'}"
```

Now I need to convert this to a python object,

```
metric=json.loads(metric)
```

but this parsing gives me this error,

```
"Error: expected string or buffer"
```

from the logs I get the datatype as 'dict'
My priority is to get metric objects in python like metric['type'] so If remove this line json.loads(metric) and if just try to access this in this manner

```
for key,value in metric:
```

I am getting this error now:

```
Value Error: too many values to unpack"
```

I am totally new to python, and also learning json, kindly help me Thanks

Comment: [json.loads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) takes in string as input, but above look like dict.

Comment: yes you are right, it is coming as dict so i added those changes